# How to downgrade poetry?

Tags: python-poetry, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

Simple:
Poetry is in version `1.2.x` and I want to downgrade it to `1.1.x`.

Is there a way to simply auto-downgrade poetry on itself?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, really simple answer: `poetry self update@1.1.15`