# Downgrade poetry version

Tags: python, python-poetry

I need to downgrade my version of `poetry` to version `1.2.1`.

Currently, it's `1.2.2`.

```
>>> poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.2.2)
```

I use the following command:

```
>>> curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | POETRY_VERSION=1.2.1 python3 -
Retrieving Poetry metadata

The latest version (1.2.1) is already installed.
```

But I'm told that `1.2.1` is already installed. Yet the poetry version is still stuck on the original.

```
>>> poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.2.2)
```

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74153270/how-to-downgrade-poetry) doesn't work (`poetry self update@1.2.1`) => `The command "self" does not exist.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think the command is `self-update` with a dash

Comment: What's the output of `which -a poetry`. I guess you have multiple installs of Poetry on your system.

Comment: have you tried to uninstall v1.2.2 before installing v1.2.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to install specific version in python hereit is ,

```
pip install poetry==1.2.1
```

In Future just simplpe

```
pip install 'Your Library Name'== 'Specific version'
```

Comment: This is only true, if you have installed Poetry via `pip`. This is explicit not recommended. Always install Poetry in it own isolated environment. Please refer to the [install instructions](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation) for more details.

Answer (score 25):

One can downgrade (or upgrade) poetry through `poetry self update` command.

So, you can downgrade to `1.2.1` by running:

```bash
poetry self update 1.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I made sure to run terminal as administrator
I then install poetry 1.2.2 with the command

```
pip install poetry=="1.2.2"
```

it installed successfully, then installed the "1.2.1" version with:

```
pip install poetry=="1.2.1"
```

The new install with a lower version automatically removed the version="1.2.2".

after you install what you need, i recommend you restart your terminal before running anything python. Maybe that will help.

if the above does not work, uninstall all poetry related packages then reinstall the 1.2.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage multiple versions of poetry, then the poetry developers recommend pipx.

A bit ironic, since poetry's job is managing software versions. Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?